# Virtualfish uninstall?

Tags: pip, virtualenv, fish, virtualfish

I pip installed virtualfish and it works, but my prompt doesn't indicate when i'm in a venv created with vf. The prompt only has the venv indicator if I create the venv without virtualfish.

I tried to follow virtualfish's instructions to `funced fish_prompt` but I'm unable to edit the function. If i try to delete or add to the function my terminal goes crazy - the existing function jumps around, duplicates lines, and won't accept my input. I've given up and want to delete virtualfish, but when I `pip uninstall virtualfish` it returns `Cannot uninstall requirement virtualfish, not installed`. It does the same if I sudo it. It doesn't appear in pip freeze either. However, `vf venv` works properly, so obviously it is installed somewhere.

This is driving me crazy and I just want it gone. How else can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to problems with removing virtualfish, make sure to leave the current venv with `vf deactivate` before running `pip uninstall`. Otherwise you'd be trying to uninstall virtualfish from the current virtualenv (which fails because it was most likely installed globally).

Comment: This sounds about right, but I'd also add that virtualfish currently doesn't do anything to your fish environment until it's loaded in `config.fish`; removing the loader line and closing and reopening fish will totally disable it and return everything to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had no difficulty running `pip uninstall virtualfish` followed by `pip uninstall virtualenv`. If you run `python -c 'import virtualfish;print(virtualfish.__path__)'` it will tell you the directory for the module.

The behavior you describe from running `funced fish_prompt` tells me your `$TERM` variable is incorrect or your editor is badly misconfigured.

P.S., This question really belongs on superuser.com since it doesn't have anything to do with programming using fish or python.